# JQuery Slider for Mobile application

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, minify

I would like to use the JQuery slider for my mobile application

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider

However, using the Slider plugin, requires me to use the entire JQuery core (29kb) + Slider plugin (6kb).

Typically, that's okay but for a mobile application - that's a lot of data.

**Question**: Anyway I can use the JQuery Slider and eliminate any bloat that might exist in the core? I would really like to reduce this 29kb core down to something much smaller. (e.g. just using Sizzle + plugin or something like that if that worked)

(Keep in mind the file sizes above is for both gzipped and compressed JS)

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in [jQTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com).

> jQTouch is a jQuery plugin with native
>   animations, automatic navigation, and
>   themes for mobile WebKit browsers like
>   iPhone, G1, and Pre.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the jQuery Mobile version of the slider : http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/forms/forms-slider.html

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at YUI2 or YUI3 slider modules.

[YUI 2 Slider](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/slider/)

[YUI 3 Slider](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/slider/)

Answer (score 0):

here's the latest version of  [JQM](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/forms/slider/)