# Slider for Mobile Devices

Tags: jquery, android, mobile

I'm looking for a horizontal slider for a mobile website (similar to [this](http://www.elmundio.net/projects/verticalSlider/)) without using jQuery Mobile.

Any ideas?

Comment: just jQuery or any framework ? (YUI ?)

Comment: Now im confused ... jQuery = OK, jQuery Mobile = not OK correct ?

Comment: How about jQuery UI ? http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Comment: Because it doesn't work on mobile devices, at least the one I'm using

Comment: jQuery mobile doesnt work on mobile devices ? im really confused now ....

Comment: You wrote "How about jQuery UI", I opened your link in my mobile browser and the slider doesn't work. jQuery-Mobile takes over a lot of CSS, I only want to implement a slider.

Comment: YUI / JQTouch -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256706/jquery-slider-for-mobile-application

Answer (score 2):

If you add [touch punch](https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch), you can use the standard jQuery UI on a touch based device.